# Java make wrong optimization

Tags: java

I have this code

```
while(!decks.get(0).isEmpty()){
   SingleCardWindow obj = new SingleCardWindow(decks.get(0).take());
   while(obj.isVisible()){

   }
   System.out.println("Closed");
}
```

SingleCardWindow it is inherit-class from JFrame. This code displays all cards from the deck. Displays one card, wait until I close this window, and displays next card. In Windows it works well.

In linux (java-oracle-7) "Closed" never writing!

But if I make

```
while(!decks.get(0).isEmpty()){
   SingleCardWindow obj = new SingleCardWindow(decks.get(0).take());
   while(obj.isVisible()){
      System.out.println("SOMETHING");
   }
   System.out.println("Closed");
}
```

program works right. So, i think that compiler optimize "while(obj.isVisible())" like "while(true)". What I should do with this? I dont needs any code into the loop.

Comment: Sounds like `obj.isVisible()` is reading from non-`volatile` members, without explicit synchronization.

Comment: And of course, a tight loop like this is a really bad idea in general...

Comment: Note that even if you make this work, you never ever should. Busy-waiting is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Polling is never a good idea. There are events: use a listener and react to them.

Comment: This is not working code, I just want to understand why Java makes it wrong.

I dont know where is isVisible() implementation and how to make it volatile, I just inherit from JFrame

Comment: Why do you believe this is a compiler optimization problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case you added this line:

```
System.out.println("SOMETHING");
```

`PrintStream#println` is a synchronized method, so if that helped your program to start working, it is a quite clear indication that the method `obj.isVisible` is *not* synchronized, and since you don't use any explicit synchronization, you are effectively causing a data race in your program. The reading thread never observes the change in the value of the `isVisible` property.

But, as many others have already noticed, this just answers the question as you have asked it; the code you have posted has many more issues with an inappropriate programming model (busy waiting) used to solve an essentially event-based problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I am really does not understand why is "data race". I have 2 threads, this is "Main thread", and "JFrame thread".
JFrame thread can change "visible" property in the JFrame object. I close it - visible = false. JFrame thread is closed, so when Main thread wake - it reads visible False. We always has visible=true, and than one time - visible=false, we dont swap value between false and true, so main thread will read right value

Comment: @chubakur if a value isn't volitile/syncronised there is no guarantee that a change made on one thread is visible on another. **They both are looking at their own local copy** (this is done because it's wildly more efficient and you can use volitile/syncronised when you need interthread communication